# How can i use a parameter as an inner array-name to my script?

Tags: bash, variable, associative-array

When i write a script named array_call_self.sh as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A num word
word=(
 [a]='index_a'
 [b]='index_b'
 [c]='index_c'
)
num=(
 [a]=1
 [b]=2
 [c]=3
)
array=${$1[@]}
for i in ${$array[@]};do
  echo $i
done
```

when i run `bash  array_call_self.sh  word`
it return me

```
test.sh: line 13: ${$1[@]}: bad substitution
test.sh: line 14: ${$array[@]}: bad substitution
```

Comment: The error messages don't seem to match the code. I get the output `word[@]`.

Comment: @Bodo Because they show a slightly modified script compared to what outputs the errors.  You would get those errors by adjusting the expansions on lines 13 and 14 to the way shown in the errors.

Comment: @HunterLiu, you're asking for help from unpaid strangers in the internet: the least you could do to make helping you easier, would be to post code that shows your issue _and matches the results/errors you say you get_. I fixed that for you, this once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you may want to use a name reference variable (available in `bash` release 4.3 or later):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

declare -A num word

word=(
 [a]='index_a'
 [b]='index_b'
 [c]='index_c'
)

num=(
 [a]=1
 [b]=2
 [c]=3
)

declare -n var="$1"

printf '%s\n' "${var[@]}"
```

This declares the variable `var` as a name reference variable, referencing the variable named by the first argument to the script.  If the first argument is not a valid name of a variable, or if it's the name `var`, then you will get an error.

After declaring `var` and assigning it the variable's name, accessing the value(s) of `var` is done as you would ordinarily access the values of the named variable.

Note that supplying the *name of a variable* on the command line of a script is highly unusable and that you instead might want to hide such implementation details and restrict the valid arguments to a limited list, possibly through doing proper command-line parsing.  The code above allows the script user to output *any of the script's variables*.

A simplistic way of restricting the values to a limited list:

```bsh
case $1 in
        (word|num) ;; # ok
        (*)
                echo 'error' >&2
                exit 1
esac

declare -n var="$1"
```